# Testing stripe shcedules

Tags: testing, subscription, schedule, stripe-payments

I'm creating stripe schedules from my app. The schedules are supposed to create a subscription in the future (like tomorrow). Then I have some logic that should be triggered when the subscription is created.

What's the easiest, quickest way to test that?

I can't find any explanation in stripe docs on how to backdate schedules or manipulate time. And obviously, I don't want to wait a day every time I want to do some live testing.

Comment: Settings the [start date](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-start_date) to a Unix timestamp several seconds/minutes in the future is generally the recommendation for testing that flow.

Comment: Thanks, that will work. But I'm hoping stripe will provide something more automatic.
For all webhooks, it would be useful to have an option to trigger a webhook instantaneously.